# JQuery Ajax Help

Tags: jquery

I have a page on my site that currently loads html via ajax. The JQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.projects a').click(function(event) {
    $('#work').load(this.href);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

and the html is:

```
<div class="projects">
    <a href="work/link.html" title="blah" id="blah">blah</a>

    <a href="work/link1.html" title="blah" id="blah">blah</a>

    <a href="work/link2.html" title="blah" id="blah">blah</a>
</div>
```

this works fine but my requirements have changed I would like to pull a certain area of the page i'm loading into the #work div. So I would like to say when .project a is clicked load the contents of #this div from this.href into #work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Loading Page Fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/) section. You can target sections of the page to be loaded by adding a selector to the url string.

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(),
>   allows us to specify a portion of the
>   remote document to be inserted. This
>   is achieved with a special syntax for
>   the url parameter. If one or more
>   space characters are included in the
>   string, the portion of the string
>   following the first space is assumed
>   to be a jQuery selector that
>   determines the content to be loaded.
>
> $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
>
> When this method executes, it
>   retrieves the content of
>   ajax/test.html, but then jQuery parses
>   the returned document to find the
>   element with an ID of container. This
>   element, along with its contents, is
>   inserted into the element with an ID
>   of result, and the rest of the
>   retrieved document is discarded.

```
$('#work').load(this.href + ' #this');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.projects a').click(function (event) {
        jQuery.get(this.href, function (response) {
            $('#work').empty().append($(response).find('#myDiv'));
        });
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```